# Why does [contenteditable] become unfocusable in Chrome 117 (and 118 beta)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have been working on a project that creates a custom element with a `<slot>` in the `shadowRoot`. Starting with the release of Chrome 117 if someone clicks on a contenteditable div the element gains focus and they can type, however if you click away and back, then the element is no longer focusable.  Here is a minimal example of this ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-kare-zpkh4s?file=/index.html:0-698)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="test-input" />

    <example-component>
      <div contenteditable="true">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is an example</p>
      </div>
    </example-component>

    <script>
      customElements.define(
        "example-component",
        class extends HTMLElement {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
            this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <slot></slot>
          `;
          }
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This bug only appears in Chrome version 117 (and 118 beta), and not in any other browsers (that I can test on my mac).  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you filed a Chromebug over this?

Comment: We are preparing one, it seems like the severity is so high that many other projects would be breaking. I can't believe we (Grammarly) are the only people using custom elements like this, so it's honestly kind of weird that I haven't already found a bug about it.

Comment: thanks @Heretic Monkey for converting the code into runnable snippet

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1484447&q=contenteditable&can=2 seems to be discussing an even simpler version of this issue, and the mitigation strategy seems to work for my code.  Looks like the Chromium team is aware and triaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Chrome ([bug #1484447](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1484447&q=contenteditable&can=2)). A recent patch was committed ([src](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/2192117acafde0eb7bb64062945d8d01fc0ce283%5E%21/#F0)) that updates `/third_party/blink/renderer/core/css/resolver/style_resolver.cc` (lines 1193 to 1201) and adds the following code:

```
// contenteditable attribute (implemented by -webkit-user-modify) should
// be propagated from shadow host to distributed node.
if (!style_request.IsPseudoStyleRequest() && element.AssignedSlot()) {
  if (Element* parent = element.parentElement()) {
    if (const ComputedStyle* shadow_host_style =
            parent->GetComputedStyle()) {
      state.StyleBuilder().SetUserModify(shadow_host_style->UserModify());
    }
  }
}
```

This allows shadow host nodes to look above to their parent nodes to see if they are editable.